# Selenium GRID: run multiple Robot Framework test suites in parallel

Tags: robotframework, selenium-grid

I have three test suites and three node machines. How can I run each test suite in parallel on two different machines? I am using RIDE to launch tests and because pybot runs test suites one by one only one node machine executes the tests. Launching multiple pybot instances from the command line is possible but I think it is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, command line is the proper way.
There is also paralel executor for robot framework, called pabot:
https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot